# desktop notification

Tags: c#, notifications, desktop

I wanna build custom desktop notification for my desktop application. notifyicon seems to be not working may be i can fix that. Can we extend notifyicon class and develop my custom desktop notification control? or do we have any tutorial about the same

Comment: You said that your notifyicon is not working.   Post your code and give details about what exactly doesn't work about it, maybe we can help fix it.

Comment: What do you exactly mean with "not working" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The class [Notifyicon](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.notifyicon.aspx) is sealed, this mean that you can not extend it.

You can create a separate window, that works like notification. But i am not aware about any tutorial for this.

Comment: +1 for providing link to documentation